# CLoudSQL permission to create schema

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to create a schema in my CloudSQL postgresql instance.

My service account user has the below roles assigned:

```
Cloud SQL Client
Cloud SQL Editor
Cloud SQL Instance User
```

And on executing the create schema command I am getting the error:
 `ERROR:  permission denied for database *******`

The google doc didn't seem to be clear on the role for specific PostgreSQL commands.

Am I doing something wrong? This works if  I give `CloudSQL Admin` role.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/add-manage-iam-users#grant-db-privileges